# Loading Images from url to StandardListItem

Tags: c++, blackberry, qml, blackberry-10

I have the following ListView in my Blackberry 10 app's QML:

```
ListView {
            id: listview
            objectName: "listview"
            dataModel: _app.model
            horizontalAlignment: HorizontalAlignment.Fill
            verticalAlignment: VerticalAlignment.Fill

            //visible: false
            listItemComponents: [
                ListItemComponent {
                    type: "item"

                    // Use a standard list item to display the data in the model
                    StandardListItem {
                        title: ListItemData.title
                        imageSource: ListItemData.poster_url
                        description: ListItemData.description
                    }                   
                }
            ]
        } // ListView
```

My app adds data to the model from network. However, it seems QML does not support loading images from the web since I get the following error:

```
"Unsupported scheme (http) used in url (http://image.url.org/xxxxx.jpg). Image loading aborted."
```

How can I handle this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Seems relevant: [Blackberry - Loading image from URL](https://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Native-Development/Loading-image-from-URL/td-p/1717927)

Comment: I have been through that conversation. No conclusive solution is provided though.

Comment: The StandardListItem can not show images loaded from URLs, you need to use a custom one, with a custom image handler that knows how to load images from URLs.

Answer (score 2):

imageview by default does not support loading images from the url . You can implement webimageview which supports loading images from the internet and use it in your listview. 
webimageview sample project is available on github

Answer (score 1):

It seems Blackberry 10.3 SDK does not support loading images from URLs. I had to implement a custom QML type that implements an image view with the source of the image being a method that fetches the image from URL using QNetworkAccess.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is just solved in the blackberry dev forum in many threads.
This is one of the solution and it should be solve your problem:

The work flow is:

1) **call setImage method**

2) **after get() method of the QNetworkAccessManager class your replyFinished() is emitted**

3) **your image is ready to use**

```
App::App()
{
    //QNetworkAccessManager m_manager;
    connect(&m_manager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)),
         this, SLOT(replyFinished(QNetworkReply*)));
}

void App::setImage(const QString &url)
{
    m_manager.get(QNetworkRequest(QUrl(url)));
}

void App::replyFinished(QNetworkReply* reply)
{
    QByteArray data = reply->readAll();

    QImage qimage;
    qimage.loadFromData(data);

    int width = qimage.width();
    int height = qimage.height();
    PixelBufferData pixelBuffer = PixelBufferData(PixelBufferData::RGBX, width, height, width, qimage.bits());

   Image image = Image(pixelBuffer);
    m_imageView->setImage(image);
}
```

[BlackBerry Forum Thread Link](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Native-Development/Loading-image-from-URL/m-p/1727771#M42733)